# How to customize the Cordapp-example

Tags: gradle, corda

I want to edit some logic from the ioustate, the flow and the contract to customize an example to make some proof of concepts.

First of all i need to change the logic, after that test and finally go to docker.
I'm using vbox with ubuntu and java version.

I'm making changes and after that using `./gradlew deploynodes` and after that `./runnodes`, but i'm having some problems that i could'n find the solution.
Should i use a different gradle task or command? i've tested with build/clean...

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: I solve it using clean before it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Will post an answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The changes being made to the CorDapp weren't being carried over to the node because Gradle was caching the build of the CorDapp.

Using `./gradlew clean deployNodes` fixed this issue.